# Codesign an executable and allow the modification of some bytes

Tags: winapi, digital-signature, code-signing, signtool, authenticode

I use [`signtool.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/signtool) to codesign a Windows [executable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format).

Which options of this tool can be used to define that **a few bytes should be omitted from the hash calculation**, and thus allowing that a digitally signed  executable can have 8 or 16 bytes modified later?

This technique has been used by Mozilla (their .exe installer is different for each download, but has the same digital signature), see [How can a .exe be modified and still keep a valid digital signature?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/260503/how-can-a-exe-be-modified-and-still-keep-a-valid-digital-signature).

The WinAPI function [`ImageGetDigestStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/imagehlp/nf-imagehlp-imagegetdigeststream) has an option `DigestLevel` to exclude resource information from the hash computation, but how to use this option when actually with `signtool.exe` or a similar tool?

Comment: What bytes are included into a signature is fixed because the signer and the verifier have to use the same specification. To my understanding Mozilla simply places the changes in fields that are by default not covered by the Authenticode signature.

Comment: I don't think signtool won't help you there. Here are a few pointers that explain this: https://isc.sans.edu/diary/It%27s+in+the+signature./22928, https://blog.didierstevens.com/2008/01/11/the-case-of-the-missing-digital-signatures-tab/ and a tool https://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/disitool/

Comment: Thank you @SimonMourier. "It is not a tool to digitally sign executables, use signtool for this."   How does disitool work, can you maybe post an answer with an example? Is there a difference between "authenticode signature" (something more specific) and general digital signature?

Comment: @Robert Which fields are by default not covered by Authenticode signature, and how to do this on any exe file?

Comment: They are mentioned in the linked answer in your question. You can also check how Mozilla did it, just get multiple versions and compare them.

Comment: Official documentation for Authenticode is here: https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/c/5/9c5b2167-8017-4bae-9fde-d599bac8184a/Authenticode_PE.docx This will tell you what is omitted from hash computation (obviously checksum and certificate data itself). disitool modifies an already signed file by modifying the cert part (disitool.py inject command)

Comment: Thank you @SimonMourier. Would you have step by step instructions to achieve this? (sign an exe, and then modify for example 2 or 4 bytes as an ID, like Mozilla does)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained by Didier Stevens in an article here: [It's in the signature](https://isc.sans.edu/diary/It%27s+in+the+signature./22928) and he also provides a tool "[disitool](https://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/disitool/)" to manipulate the signature.

Here are the steps to sign a file using [Authenticode](https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/c/5/9c5b2167-8017-4bae-9fde-d599bac8184a/Authenticode_PE.docx), and to append some data to it without breaking the signature:

A) Create a code siging certificate (you'll be required to enter passwords):

```
MakeCert /n "CN=MyOrg" /r /h 0 /eku "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3,1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.13" /sv MyOrg.pvk MyOrg.cer
```

note: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 is szOID_PKIX_KP_CODE_SIGNING and 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.13 is szOID_KP_LIFETIME_SIGNING. This will create a private key file and a certificate file.

B) Add certificate to store (needs admin rights, could be a different store):

```
Certutil -addStore TrustedPeople MyOrg.cer
```

C) Create a Pfx file to sign:

```
Pvk2Pfx /pvk MyOrg.pvk /pi [Password goes here] /spc MyOrg.cer /pfx MyOrg.pfx
```

D) Sign your file:

```
SignTool.exe sign /fd SHA256 /v /a /f MyOrg.pfx /p [Password goes here] MyFile.exe
```

At this point MyFile.exe is signed using Authenticode:

[image]

E) Create some data.txt file. I've created one that just contains the "[Kilroy was here!]" text.

F) Now run [disitool](https://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/disitool/):

```
python.exe disitool.py inject --paddata MyFile.exe data.txt MyFile2.exe
```

And here is the result,  MyFile2.exe is still valid without resigning the file:

[image]

While you can see `data.txt`'s content added to its end:

[image]

From the original file's end:

[image]

Comment: Tested, it works, thank you! In fact this script adds the bytes at the end of the exe, 8-byte padded + updates a checksum metadata in the beginning of the exe file.

Comment: If someone know, how to read this added data, please, post an answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77670397/how-to-read-altered-certificate-data-using-winapi)